# How to change title of preference page in eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

How to change the default `title` of preferences page from "Preferences" to "Settings" in Eclipse RCP?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` then I think it is not possible. The help of the same says:

> The workbench provides one common dialog box for preferences. The
>   purpose of this extension point is to allow plug-ins to **add pages** to
>   the **preference dialog box**. When preference dialog box is opened
>   (initiated from the menu bar), pages contributed in this way will be
>   added to the dialog box.

But there is a way round. Follow the below steps (**This is just showing how you can change the title text**):

1. Create an action for opening the preference dialog
2. Make a new class extending the `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog`
3. In the sub-class override the `configureShell` method
4. Invoke the `PreferenceDialog` from the above created action

***`Extended Class`***

```
class MyPreferenceDialog extends PreferenceDialog
{
    public MyPreferenceDialog(Shell parentShell, PreferenceManager manager) {
        super(parentShell, manager);
    }

    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("Settings"); 
    }
}
```

***`Code For Invocation`***

```
Button prefButton = new Button(top, SWT.PUSH);
prefButton.setText("Preference");
prefButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        final PreferenceManager preferenceManager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager();
        MyPreferenceDialog dialog = new MyPreferenceDialog(top.getShell(), preferenceManager);
        dialog.create();
        dialog.open();
    }
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    }
});
```

The resultant preference dialog looks like this:

[image]